# Node.js POST request with multipart file as parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to issue a POST request in Node.js to an API which takes two parameters: 1) "metadata", a string, and 2) "file", a multipart file.

The following is part of the server-side java code:

```
public ResponseEntity<CmisDocumentDTO> createDocument(
        @ApiParam(name = "file", value = "File to be uploaded.", required = true) @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        @ApiParam(name = "metadata", value = "Metadata of the document", required = false) @RequestParam("metadata") String metadata) {
    //Calls the service
}
```

The following is my node.js code calling this request. The file is on my local machine and uses the form-data module:

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
var form = new FormData();
form.append("metadata", "metadata_string_goes_here");
form.append("file", fs.createReadStream(fileName));

var request = https.request({
    method: 'post',
    host: 'example.org',
    path: '/upload',
    "rejectUnauthorized": false,
    headers: form.getHeaders()
});

form.pipe(request);

request.on('response', function(res) {
    console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

When I run this code, an internal service error (code: 500) is returned that says the MultipartFile parameter "file" is not present.

How do I successfully submit a POST request with a multipart file as a parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

fileName should be path of the file in local machine

```
 fs.createReadStream(fileName)
```

In case you have not given absolute path starting with root then Relative paths work, but they are relative to process.cwd(), not the currently executing module.